# How to dynamically create blank row in jexcel

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am getting no of rows and cols in ajax response from server. what i have to do is create a blank sheet for these row and col in jexcel ? Also i want automatically filled with incremental values starting from 1. I need this in a project.

Table should be like this :

Row 1 : 1 2 3 4 5 6 6 7 8

Row 2 : 9 10 11 12 continue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I assuming your are doing something like this

```
$jq = $("#jexcel-div-id").jexcel({//some params});
```

What you have to now is just create a function like

```
function dynamicExcelBuilder($rows, $cols){
var blankData = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < parseInt($row); i++) {
            var tmpData = [];
             var counter = 1;
            for (var j = 0; j < parseInt($col); j++) {
                tmpData.push(counter);
                counter++;
            }
            $('#jexcel-div-id').jexcel('insertRow', tmpData);
        }
        return blankData;
}
```

Just call this function and pass rows, cols. Enjoy it.

Comment: You don't need to create a loop for blank data. This is enough: $('#my').jexcel('insertRow', numOfRows, rowNumber) where rowNumber is the reference you want - 0 = beginning of the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inserRow` excel method for this. By just creating a simple push method which assign incremental values that's it. You can also see example here : https://bossanova.uk/jexcel/examples/working-with-the-data

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new row with data, for example:

```
<script>
$('#my').jexcel('insertRow', [ 'Pears', 10, 0.59, '=B2*C2' ], 1)
</script>
```

For more than one row

```
<script>
$('#my').jexcel('insertRow', numOfRows, rowNumber)
</script>
```

numOfRows = How many row do you want
rowNumber = Row reference - 0 for the beginning of the table, or blank for the last row.

Answer (score 0):

Is this you want to create empty sheet you could

```
$.fn.jexcel('helper', { action:'createEmptyData', cols:6, rows:10 })
```

Check [jexcel jquery plugin](https://bossanova.uk/jexcel/examples/multiple-spreadsheets-in-the-same-page)